# Code cant take 'key' value and thus cant select encryption key on caesar cypher

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to python. The initial version I wrote had a fixed 
  key which was represented as well in `abc.index(c)+3` lets say. I thought of a 
  small upgrade and decided to let the user input the encryption key. Now if I 
  inputed encryption keys 1-4, the code would work but anything over would not. 
  Im a bit stuck now.

```
abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyz"
key = int(input("what is the encryption key you desire"))
plain = input("what is the word/sentence you want to encode?: ")
cipher = "";
for c in plain:
    if c.isalpha() : cipher += abc[(abc.index(c)+key)%26]
    else: cipher += c
print(cipher)
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what is the error or problem?

Comment: Can you show the example which does not work?

Comment: silly mistake `abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"` you missed v character

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Check whether it requires user input or whether you can achieve the same using a hard-coded values, too!

Answer (score -1):

replace abc with

```
import string
abc=string.ascii_lowercase
```